# How to strip and split a string which contains an escape sequence in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a string. For example

```sh
STR="          Hello, World    I'm\ new\ here  "
```

and what I want to receive is an array like this

```sh
"Hello,"
"World"
"I'm new here"
```

or at least something iterable so I can iterate over these "words" and do manipulations with them. Thanks!

Comment: Please kindly read [ask]. What research did you do? What have you tried? `How to..` write a parser that does that.

Comment: @alkatraz : So you basically want to parse a string on unescaped white space, and turn it into an array? Please show your own attempt to this problem. If I would do it, I would implement a small state machine and iterate over the individual characters of the string.

Comment: The apostrophe makes this somewhat difficult, since you clearly do not want to use the usual shell parsing rules to split your string.  Which means you'll need to build your own parser.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe all restrictions that may apply to the string. Can there be any other backslashes in the string except those for marking space characters that should be part of a "word" and not used for splitting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `read`.

```
$ STR="          Hello, World    I'm\ new\ here  "
$ read -a x <<< "$STR"
$ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="Hello," [1]="World" [2]="I'm new here")
```

`read` performs word-splitting on its input as usual; the `-a` option causes each word to be stored as a separate element of the array, rather than storing words in individual variables. `read`'s default behavior is to replace escape sequences with the character they represent: in this case, `'\ '` represents `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't mind a solution using more steps, you can use

```
echo "          Hello, World    I'm\ new\ here  " |
  sed 's/\\ /\r/g' | grep -Eo "[^ ]*" | sed 's/\r/ /g'
```

One pipe less makes the regex more complicated:

```
echo "          Hello, World    I'm\ new\ here  " | 
  grep -Eo "([^ ]*([\] )*)+[^ ]*" | sed 's/\\ / /g'
```

With GNU `sed` you can have a different approach:

```
echo "          Hello, World    I'm\ new\ here  " |
  sed -z 's/ /\n/g; s/\\\n/ /g' | grep .
```